# why does the set of all linear functions form a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear functions $f_1(x) = m_1 x+b_1$ and $f_2(x) = m_2 x+b_2$. Why does the set of all linear functions form a subspace (of the function space of all real functions)? Find two linear functions that span this subspace.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Do you know the properties of a subspace?

Answer (score 3):

The set of all these functions is not empty, since the null function belongs to it.

If $f_1(x)=m_1x+b_1$ and $f_2(x)=m_2x+b_2$, then $(f_1+f_2)(x)=(m_1+m_2)x+(b_1+b_2)$, which is again a function of the same type.

If $f(x)=mx+b$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, then $(\alpha f)(x)=\alpha(mx+b)=\alpha mx+\alpha b$, which is again a function of the same type.

Therefore, your set is a subspace. It is generated by the funcions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1$.